# C# Parse elements from text file

Tags: c#, file, parsing, text

I've got a text file with the following content:

```
139862,2 - 455452,6 - 13:24:53 

139860,8 - 455452,2 - 13:25:13 

139859,3 - 455452,2 - 13:25:33
```

As you can see there are 3 elements per line of the text file. I'd like to be able to save these as variables.

It's possible for me to put prefixes per variable that I'd like to be able to save, so that the text will look like:

```
X:139862,2 - Y:455452,6 - D:13:24:53 

X:139860,8 - Y:455452,2 - D:13:25:13 

X:139859,3 - Y:455452,2 - D:13:25:33
```

What I've already got is the coding to read the text file line for line, which looks like:

```
    string line;
    System.IO.StreamReader file = new System.IO.StreamReader(filePath);
    while ((line = file.ReadLine()) != null)
    {
        // Here I'd like to parse the text file and add them to a list for example
    }
```

**Thanks in advance!**

Comment: what effort have you made to actually processing the data?

Comment: Look at [String.Split()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.split%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used StringReader but you can replace with StgreamReader to read from a file

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.IO;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string input =
            "139862,2 - 455452,6 - 13:24:53\n" +
            "139860,8 - 455452,2 - 13:25:13\n" +
            "139859,3 - 455452,2 - 13:25:33\n";

            string inputLine = "";
            StringReader reader = new StringReader(input);
            while((inputLine = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
            {
                string[] inputArray = inputLine.Split(new char[] { ' ' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
                Console.WriteLine("X:{0} {1} Y:{2} {3} D:{4}", inputArray[0], inputArray[1], inputArray[2], inputArray[3], inputArray[4]);
            }
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `string.Split`, `float.Parse` and `DateTime.Parse`

```
string line;
System.IO.StreamReader file = new System.IO.StreamReader(filePath);
while ((line = file.ReadLine()) != null)
{
    string[] parts = line.Split('-');
    float x = float.Parse(parts[0].Trim(), NumberFormatInfo.InvariantInfo);
    float y = float.Parse(parts[1].Trim(), NumberFormatInfo.InvariantInfo);
    DateTime d = DateTime.Parse(parts[2].Trim(), DateTimeFormatInfo.InvariantInfo);

    Console.WriteLine("X: {0}, Y: {1}, D: {2}", x, y, d);
}
```

Note that `*.Parse` throws an exception if the string is not valid. So you may want to use `TryParse` instead or wrap it in a `try/catch` block.

I use `*FormatInfo.InvariantInfo` to make sure the `,` and `:` are parsed correctly.

If you have a data class like that

```
public class Record
{
    public float X { get; set; }
    public float Y { get; set; }
    public DateTime D { get; set; }
}
```

you can generate a list of those records through your loop:

```
List<Record> records = new List<Record>();
string line;
System.IO.StreamReader file = new System.IO.StreamReader(filePath);
while ((line = file.ReadLine()) != null)
{
    string[] parts = line.Split('-');
    records.Add(new Record {
        X = float.Parse(parts[0].Trim(), NumberFormatInfo.InvariantInfo),
        Y = float.Parse(parts[1].Trim(), NumberFormatInfo.InvariantInfo);
        D = DateTime.Parse(parts[2].Trim(), DateTimeFormatInfo.InvariantInfo)});
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The solution for this problem could be done pretty straight-forwardly:

```
string line;
System.IO.StreamReader file = new System.IO.StreamReader(filePath);
List<string> newlines = new List<string>(); //here to store your List of string
string[] delimiters = new string[] { " - " }; //declared only once outside of while loop
while ((line = file.ReadLine()) != null)
{
    string[] words = line.Split(delimiters);
    newlines.Add("X:" + words[0] + " - Y:" + words[1] + " - Z:" + words[2]);
}
```

And your final result would in the `newlines`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
string[] stringParsed = line.split(" - ");
```